# Unable to load library in ColdFusion 11

Tags: c++, dll, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am getting the following error when I run my application on ColdFusion 11:

```
Unable to load library encrypt.dll
```

I have recently migrated my applications from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11. It works fine on ColdFusion 9 without a single problem but not on ColdFusion 11. The referenced dll is present in the specified location. I don't understand the reason behind it.

The path to the dll in Admin is correct.

> **Extensions > CFX Tags > Manage C++ CFX > "Path of dll"**.

The bitness of the operating system and ColdFusion server is 64 bit.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a 32-bit dll?

Answer (score 0):

Does encrypt.dll call another dll? We faced a similar problem with 32bit ColdFusion on 64bit Windows. The called dll was in the same directory as the cfx dll. But the cfx could not find the called dll.

We solved it by copying the called dll to the c:\windows\syswow64 directory. In your case, it would be c:\windows\system32

Note that Microsoft cleverly misnames the directories for backwards compatibility. On 64 bit systems, syswow64 is for 32 bit. system32 is for 64bit.